# What will happen to existing apps that do not update and integrate sign in with Apple?

Tags: ios, apple-sign-in

According to the latest update from Apple, June 30th is the deadline fo apps to incorporate sign-in with Apple (as required based on this guideline: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#sign-in-with-apple).

Is this true only for app updates that will be submitted after June 30? What will happen to existing apps that aren't updated? Will they stop working?

Comment: The new guidelines only apply to new or updated apps. Existing apps will continue without Sign In with Apple

Comment: i see. Thank you so much!